# Writing a test class for a for loop based method

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment, code-coverage

I wrote the below code and test method for it, but for some reason my test method is not providing sufficient coverage for deployment. I run out of ideas on how to increase the coverage of this test method. Any advice on how to do it?

Actual code:

```
public class  standardiseWebsites {

    public static void standardiseWebsites(){
    //extracting the host from the address for websites that have web-protocol (http:// and https://)
    list<Account> accts = [SELECT Website FROM Account WHERE Website LIKE 'http://%' OR Website LIKE 'https://%'];
        for (Account acct : accts){            
            string website = acct.Website;
            Url u = new Url(acct.Website);
            acct.Website = u.getHost();
            update acct;
        }

      //removing first 4 digits of the address if it starts with 'www.' (non-web-protocol values)
      list<Account> accts2 = [SELECT Website FROM Account WHERE Website LIKE 'www.%'];
        for (Account acct2 : accts2){
            string website = acct2.website;
            website = website.substring(4);
            acct2.website = website;
            update acct2;
        }
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
@isTest
public class standardiseWebsitesTest {

        static void standardiseWebsitesTest() {
        standardiseWebsites.standardiseWebsites();
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be best time to learn writing test classes from trailhead or other sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would strongly suggest you head over to Trailhead and start learning more about the purpose of [Apex unit testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro). It is not all about getting passed the code coverage threshold but rather setting your focus on testing the expected output of your implementation. See [What to Test](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_what.htm).

The test class you have at the minute is testing nothing, simply because of there no assertion() methods.

The following is a quick implementation of a test class that will test your code at a very minimal level. It will give you a head start on how you should be testing, but please keep in bulkification and other [Apex Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm).

```
@isTest
public class standardiseWebsitesTest {

    static testmethod void standardiseWebsiteHTTP() {
        testSetup('HTTP', 'http://I_AM_HTTP', true);
    }

    static testmethod void standardiseWebsitesWWW() {
        testSetup('WWW', 'WWW.I_AM_WWW', false);
    }

    public static void testSetup(String accName, String accWebsite, Boolean webProtocol) {
        Account acc = new Account(
            Name = accName,
            Website = accWebsite
        );
        insert acc;

        standardiseWebsites.standardiseWebsites();
        Account updatedAccount = [select Website from Account where id = :acc.Id];
        if(webProtocol) {
            Url u = new Url(acc.Website);
            System.assert(u.getHost() == updatedAccount.Website);
        } else {
            System.assert(updatedAccount.Website == acc.Website.substring(4));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SantanuBoral, above is a simple test class but provides some learning steps too. As noted, there are improvements needed by the OP but sometimes we all need a little guidance.